# Top contributors report for MOSS site collection

Tags: 2007, site-usage

I'm looking for a simple way to identify the top contributors (content created by or modified by) across my entire site collection. This is strictly for my own use as an adoption tool (think "user of the month") so I don't need an elegant presentation, just the data. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable usage processing in Central administration then turn on auditing in the site collection.  The data can be a bit of a bear to work with, but the reports you can create are flexible enough that you could retrieve some of that data.  There are other third party tools that will give you a better grasp on usage and content better if you're looking for a long term solution.

Comment: Correct about the data being a bear to work with... it might be an architecture issue but I can't seem to pull audit data through the UI (site collection audit reports) that spans any reasonable (like monthly) period without bringing down the site collection. Was hoping for a little magic but will be acquiring a reporting tool from Axceler or AvePoint soon and may have to wait for implementation.

Comment: What we've done is to create a separate database then use a timed SQL job to push the auditdata and UserInfo tables to it.  The data push has a filter on it so we're only pushing the data we want.  Then I can open that database in SSMS and create any reports I want.

Comment: What kind of content do you want to monitor? auditing is not available for publishing pages (broken) and not implemented (per design PSS say) for items

Answer (score 0):

It would be pretty "expensive", but you could use a Data View Web Part (DVWP) with DataSourceMode="CrossList" to count items per user. Since if sounds like you'd run it infrequently, the "expense" might not matter.

The good thing about this approach is that you'd have a lot of control over what you got.